# continuous bash script - show custom error when process killed

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script that keeps checking if process "XXX" gets killed and if it does, show error message with text from /proc/XXX_ID/fd/1 and start again.

I am trying to make it work on custom thinclient distro where is no more packages than needed. Linux 4.6.3TS_SMP i686

I am new in scripting in Bash and I can't seem to get it working. I were googling and trying different things last two days and I moved nowhere. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ] ; do
    process_ID="$(pgrep XXX)"
    tail -f /proc/${process_ID}/fd/1 > /bin/test2.txt
```

Everything works till now. Now I need to somehow check if test2.txt is empty or not and if its not, use text from it as error message and start checking again. I tried something like this

```
    if [ -s /bin/test2.txt ]
    then
        err="$(cat /bin/test2.txt)"
        notify-send "${err}"
    else 
    fi

done
```

Comment: `tail -f` blocks your script. What do you want to follow by `-f`? Are you trying to steal the standard output of another program? You should use the `--pid` option of `tail`, if you want to wait until the process dies.

Comment: I honestly don't know if the tail is the right thing to use right now. With the `tail -f` I was trying to get information from the fd/1. It is empty if no error happened and for example if user wrote down wrong password, there would be written "error: wrong password." Its the only place (as far as I know) where is the error that happened actually written. And I couldnt find out different way to use the text from it and use it as error message. Was I clear enough?

Comment: Standard output is 1 and standard error is 2. But you will not be able to ever read anything from the file descriptors in /proc/*/fd/*, because some other program will read the output before you.

Comment: Well when I go only with `tail -f /proc/ID/fd/1 `and I do something that goes into error, it normally shows it. So is it different than the script somehow? The process is AuthManagerDaemon.
`Josef:/bin# tail -f /proc/7890/fd/1 ` and it goes: "Credential error loading application list:DPErrorId: CharlotteErrorBadCredentials[0]." Which is exactly what I want to use as the error message.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
output_filepath=$(readlink /proc/$pid/fd/1)
while ps $pid > /dev/null
do
  sleep 1
done
tail "$output_filepath"
```

The whole idea only works if the stdout (fd 1) of the process is redirected into a file which can be read by someone else.  Such a redirect will result in `/proc/<pid>/fd/1` being a symlink.  We read and memorize the target of that symlink in the first line.

Then we wait until the `ps` of the given PID fails which typically means the process has terminated.  Then we tail the file at the memorized path.

This approach has several weaknesses.  The process (or its caller) could remove, modify, or rename the output file at termination time, or reading it can somehow be impossible (permissions, etc.).  The output could be redirected to something not being a file (e.g. a pipe, a socket, etc.), then tailing it won't work.

`ps` not failing does not necessarily mean that the same process is still there.  It's next to impossible that a PID is reused that quickly, but not completely impossible.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like the `ps` is never failing and always goes only into sleep for some reason. When I ps existing or nonexisting PID, it always does the same thing, it just shows all processes and adds my "ps 9999" into them and adds to it its own PID.

Comment: you can use `ls /proc/$pid > /dev/null` instead of `ps $pid > /dev/null`.

Comment: Sorry, missclicked and couldn't edit it after I realised.
I tried it and alteast it did something. Now it says: "
_tail: can't open 'root/.ICAClient/.tmp/.storebrowse.stderr': No such file or directory. tail: no files_ " I tried to look into the .tmp/ directory and the .storebrowse.stderr is here, but  `cat` gives nothing. Its empty? I tried to `ls -la` while restarting the application and it gets deleted for few sec and gets created as the application starts again. All I need is to give users error message when they write wrong credentials, weren't expecting it being issue for few days..